# Call BindingGroup.CommitEdit in MVVM style

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a binding group because that is apparently the only way that a ValidationRule can be aware of the data context. *If there is a way around this, that is an acceptable answer as well.* My architecture is MVVM so I don't want a bunch of TextChanged event handlers in my code behind. How can I call BindingGroup.CommitEdit when the binding within said binding group changes.

I really don't want to use IDataErrorInfo. I've used it in the past. It doesn't suit my current project.

Comment: *I don't understand why WPF makes validation so complex*... it doesn't. `ValidationRule`s are UI related, so you shouldn't use them in an MVVM project. Instead, try using [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx) and the [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) interfaces. *I don't want to use IDataErrorInfo. It doesn't suit my current project*... why not?

Comment: I don't want to use a massive switch statement among other things. I've also used Data Annotations quite a lot. I want my UI to be responsive to user interaction. I don't want them to have to click a button to see an error. I guess that's what the INotifyDataErrorInfo is for. No? And yes, it is very complex. I find myself spending way too much time on validating a simple form. Every how-to that I find seems to cover too specific a case. I have pretty heavy business rules, and I'm not working with database records. All I want to do is make sure that the name they give this object is unique.

Comment: I've read the MSDN article on INotifyDataErrorInfo and it horrified me! I don't have time for this. I'm just going to write an event to call BindingGroup.CommitEdit. I want my validation to be IN THE FORM, what is so wrong with that? I understand that it is useful to wrap validation up into entities, but what about validation that depends on use and state? I know that my question here is probably going to be closed, but I would still love an answer.

Comment: On the one hand you are using MVVM and on the other you are adding validation in the View. These validations cannot be (unit)tested with the ViewModel and the ViewModel has to rely on the View for validation. That is all a bit backwards and it makes it harder to give a proper solution.

Comment: You just think that it's complex because you haven't learned how to use it properly yet. Once you have set up your `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implementation, then you can validate any way you want, be that pro-actively or post typed. Also, once you have that implementation, then validating an object becomes as simple as adding a few parameters to a few `Attribute`s in your data type class. Using this interface, you can also easily display either all validation errors or just ones for individual properties. I suggest that you just take the time to learn how to use the correct tools for the job.

Comment: Does it make sense to extend INotifyDataErrorInfo in my view model?

Comment: @Jordan This comment thread is outstanding. _"I don't have time for this."_ Did you know that good software isn't cheap or fast? Surprise!

Comment: @Gusdor, this is more than two years ago at a different job.